# Memory allocation always increasing, despite not using my app

Tags: memory-management, ios7

I am currently updating my app, and I have been facing a very strange and complex problem for the last few days. The part of the application that is problematic is made of one UITableViewController that is a list of news, and (after you click on a news) a detail view which is in fact a UICollectionView with as many details CollectionViewCells as there are news.

Each of these can have an infinite amount of elements, and are loaded 20 by 20 when the user scrolls to the bottom of the TableView (or to cell that is at the furthest position right on the CollectionView). Also, inside a DetailsCollectionViewCell, there can be another UICollectionView, containing images.

My problem is that after scrolling a few details views, after behaving normally (ie memory is allocated when I change the page, then stabilize until I change the page again, and so on), the memory allocation start to ramp up slowly but steadily, even if I stop doing anything at all. Also, the CPU usage will go to 100-120% and stay there, whatever I do, even, again, if I don't touch anything. After a while, the UICollectionView and the UITableView will not render any animation anymore, thus loosing the paging, and the inertia when scrolling, and overall resulting in a very poor user experience.

The strange thing is, I can observe these behaviours via XCode 5's Debug Navigator, but when I try to use instrument to find the source of the leaks/allocations, the allocation graph is normal, and I get 40-60 MB mem usage, no more, despite still observing the animations/paging problems.

Has anyone already met such a strange behaviour, and can someone help me in finding the cause of all this fuss ? (maybe by fixing Instruments ?)

Thank you all in advance, don't hesitate to ask me for more infos if needed !

Comment: Thing is, I don't know which part of my code to post, even if I know that I have to be more specific. To be able to post some code I'll need hints as to where this could come from. It's specifically because I could not find where it is coming from that I posted this new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problems in the meantime.

About the difference in Memory usage between Xcode 5's Debug Navigator and Instruments, it was caused by my use of NSZombies. I have the habit of always setting them on, and that just flew off my mind... To remove them : Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Objects (just unmark it).

The cause of my CPU usage was an animation that was going on indefinitely in the background on multiple pages. The solution was to first of all stop it as soon as it is not seen/useful anymore, the optimise it by changing my approach (I was using CAAnimation and moved on to using UIView's animate function).

I think I might have pulled the trigger a bit too fast here, but hey... if this can help someone later, then it will not be a waste !